# Does the fuel selector switch of a Cessna 172 automatically turn 180° when pulling fuel shut off?

Tags: fuel-systems, cessna-172

I noticed this behaviour in X-Plane 11 using the LR Cessna model and I'm wondering if this resembles the correct behaviour of a real aircraft.

Also it seems that in X-Plane after pulling the fuel shut off you can't move the selector anymore to a single storage tank, but only by 180° at a time.

Is that behaviour "realistic"? How are the selector switch and the shut off connected in real-world aircrafts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not connected in real aircraft.  Both are manual, mechanical controls, and the only thing the have in common is that they both control valves related to fuel.  What you are seeing is definitely a software glitch.